# How did the jamádagni-s, a fairly small and late clan in the R̥g-vedá, rise to such prominence in sū́tra-s?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, gotra

How did the Jamádagni-s, a fairly small and late clan in the R̥g-vedá, rise to such prominence in sū́tra-s?

Below I give an explanation as to why the Jamádagni-s were considered to be a minor clan in the R̥g-vedá, and why they are considered to have risen to great prominence in the sū́tra-s.

In the r̥g veda there are hymns known as the āprī sūkta-s which are employed during sacrifices for a certain diety. There are 10 āprī hymns in the Şākala-saṁhitā́, viz. 1.13 by medhātithi kāṇva, 1.142 by dīrghatamas aucathya, 1.188 by agastya maitrāvaruṇi, 2.3 by gṛtsamada śaunaka, 3.4 by gāthina viśvāmitra, 5.5 by vasuśruta ātreya, 7.2 by vasiṣṭha, 9.5 by asita kāśyapa, 10.70 by sumitra vādhryaśca, and finally 10.110 by rāma jāmadagnya.

All the composers belong to major clans in the Şākala-saṁhitā́, like the kāṇva-s of book 8, gautama-s of book 4, the viśvāmitra-s of book 3, the atri-s of book 5, the vasiṣṭha-s of book 7, the kāśyapa-s in various scattered hymns of the later books, the only outliers are the agastya-s and the jamadagni-s.

The agastya-s were a minor clan in the Şākala-saṁhitā́, and this translated to being put last in the pravara-adhyāya-s of the śrauta-sūtra-s.

But the jamadagni-s, who were also a minor clan in the Şākala-saṁhitā́, having around 13 hymns to their name, (The number does not increase significantly if we include the hymns of other bhārgava composers) rose to great importance by the time of the śrauta-sūtra-s, where they were put first in the pravara-adhyāya-s. They were also numerically the largest clan in the śrauta-sūtra-s.

One explanation is that the jamadagni clan was a later vrātya clan who were assimilated into aryan society later on.

References:

https://www.jstor.org/stable/41688765?read-now=1&seq=7

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/rig-veda-english-translation

Comment: I suggest you to read the Āśvalāyana & Sāṁkhyāyana saṁhitās of the Ṛgveda in order to get the larger picture.

Comment: Here is the link to Āśvalāyana https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/asvalayana-samhita-of-rgveda-with-padapatha-vol-i-mandalas-5-vol-ii-mandalas-6-10-in-two-volumes-sanskrit-only-ihe087/

Comment: Here is the link to Sāṁkhyāyana https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/rigveda-samhita-sankhayan-with-padapatha-set-of-4-volumes-nzh114/

Comment: Aryan society.? If it's about Aryan -Dravid theory then this theory is totally fake.

Comment: @অনু What specifically should I be looking for? Is there an Anu-krámaṇī for the Āśvalāyana and Sāṁkhyāyana schools?